# При использовании certbot ошибка "Set the `server_name` directive"

Tags: centos, ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

Пытаюсь накатить LetsEncrypt на сервер с CentOS, при вводе команды "certbot --nginx -d mysite.ru -d www.mysite.ru" выходит ошибка, гласящая:
"Could not automatically find a matching server block for mysite.ru. Set the `server_name` directive to use the Nginx installer".
В директории /etc/nginx/sites-available/ есть два одинаковых файла, на всякий случай - nginx.conf и mysite.ru, внутри которых есть строка "server_name mysite.ru www.mysite.ru;"

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил - сам ответил.
Nginx брал конфиг из другой директории, который я и не трогал.